# Android apk version

Tags: java, android

I am building an android app. Eclipse lists my android version of the project as 4.1 (I do know how to change this).

I now how to see and change the minimum and max. version number of android devices needed for compatibility (this is 10-15 in my case), which are in the android manifest file.

I have a very simple question, but I just need somebody to confirm as I have not been able to get a clear answer to my (very beginner) question.

If eclipse lists my android version as 4.1, is the project is apk generated only for 4.1? In other words, do I need to generate a apk with eclipse settings on 4.0.3 to execute the file on a 4.0.3 device? Or does the compatibility setting (10-15) automatically imply this.

Sorry, I am a bit confused between compiling for a platform and compatibility of methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If eclipse lists my android version as 4.1, is the project is apk generated only for 4.1?
```

The answer is No. Android requires a run-time of Android 1.5 or later (set android:minSdkVersion to at least 3 in your AndroidManifest.xml). This means you can develop with the latest version of the Android SDK and your app will still run on an earlier Android version (1.5 minimum).`So if you compile with 4.1(set in project.properties android-14) and set minsdkversion 3 the you can run it with any device` also read the Requirements from this link https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/

Answer (score 1):

Compatibility setting is enough. I'm developing an app with compat setting set to 8-15, Eclipse displays it as 4.1 but it runs very well on my 2.3.5 device.